GridBagConstraints.fill no funciona y agranda los componentes
Estoy usando Java Swing y no encuentro la forma de que se muestre el contenido de la forma que quiero con ningún layout:
El resultado de mi código actual es el siguiente:

private class PCrearPartida extends JPanel{
    
    TextField nombrePartida;
    
    public PCrearPartida() {
        super();
        setBorder(new CompoundBorder(
                new TitledBorder("Crear partida"), 
                new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20)                               
            ));     
                    
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());         
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();          
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;                     
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;

        
        add(new JLabel("Nombre de tu partida : "),gbc);
        
        nombrePartida = new TextField();    
        gbc.gridx=1;    
        add(nombrePartida,gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        gbc.gridwidth=2;
        add(new JButton ("Crear Partida"),gbc);
        
        

Y yo quiero que se muestre de esta manera PERO sin agregarle manualmente el tamaño ni las coordenadas X o Y a los píxeles ya que me parece muy poco flexible y chapucero hacer esas cosas manualmente en lugar de que los layout lo gestionen dinámicamente:

Si uso un BorderLayout con el textfield como CENTER, se convierte en cuadrado que ocupa todo el pane. Estoy usando el GridBagLayout pero le pone un tamaño diminuto porque el GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL no hace nada.
Intento cuidar el código limpio lo máximo posible, ¿Se os ocurre algún layout que lo deje como quiero o alguna forma de que el GridBagLayout lo ponga bien sin la necesidad de crear decenas de paneles y layout que haga inleíble el código?
Muchas gracias!!

En ese codigo, indica el ancho nombrePartida = new TextField(20); y para separar, por ejemplo, 30 px verticalmente el boton de los otros dos componentes usa gbc.insets = new Dimension(30,0,0,0);
